# What should we do with the Kirkus question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We have an [old question about the usefulness of getting reviews from Kirkus](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/4961/1993).  Many of the answers are personal-experience testimonials about the poor quality of this service.  They are mostly all saying the same things.

These are being posted by new users, so protecting the question will fend off more of them, but what should we do with the existing ones, all of which are upvoted?

Is the problem the question?  While it is somewhat opinion-based, it's gotten a good answer explaining the difference between reviews and critiques and giving good guidance.  To me that says a question in this space *can* be answerable.  Also, the question isn't just a one-liner "what do you guys think of Kirkus?" (which I trust would have been closed); it lays out what the OP is trying to achieve and asks if this is a reasonable way to go about it.  This is an approach to asking that we want to encourage.

So, what should we do with this question and its collection of answers?

Answer (score 2):

Having reviewed that question, the accepted answer provides really useful general information. I think the question could be altered to make it a little more generic, maybe still including the specific service.

The other answers are anecdotes about the specific service described in the question. I think these should be removed, primarily because although they technically provide an answer the question, it boils down to "don't do it" without really giving an explanation besides "because they screwed me" which doesn't help other people avoid similar situations with different companies. Also, I found myself wondering if maybe these people were crappy writers and didn't get good reviews because their work wasn't good. That's a distraction from the real question, which is whether a paid review is worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is useful and the accepted answer is good (hemm, hemm).

I can see that more recent answers are simply testimonials, and getting more doesn't add any value to the question. Therefore, protection is a good idea.

I think testimonials are technically acceptable answers, as they constitute answering the question from personal experience. I would hope that individual testimonials will not be voted as highly as the informative, in-depth answer (hemm, hemm); and since that seems to remain the case, I don't feel additional testimonials do enough damage to merit deletion. They're legitimate answers to a legitimate questions; you can downvote them (as failing to add information, or just being poorly written), but I don't see them as being deletion-worthy. (I prefer to tread very lightly with deletions for posts which are reasonable attempts to answer a question. "This isn't an answer" is deletion, "This isn't a good answer" is merely a downvote.)

Bottom line: **Leave the question open; protect the question; leave existing answers in place.**